# How can get list of records in interval from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, time

I want to get a list of records in a continuous time interval like hour, day, minutes etc for show in graph. tha graph data contains different kind of values like market price of currencys or assect, growth reports and many more things like that.

select * from records

Answer (score 0):

--For getting records of every 1 minutes--

SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) /(1 * 60));

--For getting records of every 1 hour--

SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY hour(created_at);

--
SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY floor(hour(created_at) / 1);

--
SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) /(1 * 60*60));

--For getting records of every 2 hour--
SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY floor(hour(created_at) / 2);

SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) /(2 * 60*60));

--For getting records of every 1 day--
SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY day(created_at);